# CSH: How to tokenize a string

Tags: tokenize, csh

I'm making a CSH script where I am looping through the file names in a directory:

```
foreach i ($INPUTDIR/*)
     $i
end
```

i ends up being something like this:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/fileNameHead_middle_2016080924
```

My question is, using CSH, how can I tokenize each path, first splitting on the forward slashes, then on the underscores, collecting only the last token?

Answer (score 0):

The `basename` utility deletes any prefix ending with the last slash / character present in string (after first stripping trailing slashes), and a suffix, if given. On my system there's also a `gbasename` which is part of GNU coreutils which does essentially the same thing with a few more options.

`basename` is part of POSIX, so it's safe to use everywhere.